# Pentaho : How to convert a string datatype into XML datatype using pentaho transformation

Tags: xml, postgresql, csv, pentaho

Have a requirement to extract data from CSV file and then transform it into XML to finally load into target.

The data in the CSV file is

```
Number,Email,Email Communication,Member Type,VIN
85320000399,test@hotmail.com,TRUE,CANLAN,TEST
81890000887,test@hotmail.com,TRUE,CANLAN,TEST
85480001175,xx@live.ca,TRUE,CANLAN,TEST
85370001847,abc@hotmail.com,TRUE,CANLAN,TEST
85500000418,123ftremblay.ca,TRUE,CANLAN,TEST
```

XML format

```
<MemberUpdate>
<MemId>85320000399</MemId>
<emailAddress>test@gmail.com</emailAddress> 
<optInFlag>true</optInFlag>
<memberType>CANLAN</memberType>
</MemberUpdate>
```

POSQTGRESQL table column is of XML datatype

I created a transformation to do the above but I get an error.

```
ERROR: column "content" is of type xml but expression is of type character varying.
Hint: You will need rewrite or cast the expression.
```

[image]

The transformation ran successfully when I changed to the table datatype to "character varying" in my local DB. But I want to do this without making any changes to the database. As we cannot make any changes to the "Prod database." I am looking for a way to convert the xml string output generated by the "ADD XML" transformation into actual XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Another efficient way to get the result is by eliminating the "Table output" and "Block" steps  instead use insert script in the Execute SQL script transformation to load the data into the target. The insert script should be something like this

INSERT INTO workflow_transaction columns(workflow_transaction_id,content_data)
VALUES (?,'?');

NOTE: With the insert script we don't need to exclusively the cast the input datatype to xml.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

So here's what I did I removed the XML column from the "Table output" then I added a "Block this step until steps finish" transformation to wait for the target to be load all the columns (expect XML). Then I used a "Execute SQL Script" in which I ran the below script

```
UPDATE workflow_transaction SET content_data = ('?' ::xml) where workflow_transaction_id = ?
```

Update here updates the tables and inserts values into XML column by converting the string output from the ADD XML step into actual XML.

I don't quite know how correct my answer is but I got the desired result using the sample data. There may or may not be future complications but it servers my purpose for now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the XML data type on the database, as PDI doesn't understand it. Use varchar or text only.

Comment: I cannot do that. Is there any way that I can convert a string into xml using Pentaho transformation?

Comment: Xml is just a string. From PDI's point of view, it's just a string. And I don't think it'll understand that XML is a separate data type on the database.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out. But I 'am seriously struggling to complete this task have been trying everything just to make it run (without changes the database structure).